# Procedure to include a diagram/image/picture in a post

Tags: support, links, image

How do I include a diagram that will simplify my question, mostly in concepts like kinematic or Newton's Laws of Motions? I searched the site but didn't find a way to include it.

(If this question has already been asked and has an answer, please add a link and close this one.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To insert pictures, you can click the handy "Image" button above the question/answer field:

[image: image button]

This will prompt you to locate the picture either on your computer or on the internet. It will upload it to StackExchange's special imgur account<sup>1</sup> and insert the appropriate formatted link in the text field. Note that you are encouraged to replace the highlighted text with some image description.

[image: pre-formatted image link]

---

As for *making* diagrams, there is no particular toolset on the site.<sup>2</sup> We do have many [suggestions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401), though, for standalone tools. Use whichever you want, and upload the result.

Why nothing integrated into the site? You can make a request, but as you'll see in that last link, there are many different opinions about what works best. Besides, whatever option there is has to be amenable to integrating into websites.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should do this rather than just format an appropriate link to the image. This way the picture is permanently stored even if there is link rot.

<sup>2</sup> Unlike, for instance [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), which has a [tool for making circuit diagrams](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2708).